# Pickling an object on appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pickle

I have an object with an `__init__` procedure that requires at least one parameter and

I want to store in the cache.

When trying to getting the object from the cache I get an error that the I didn't pass enough parameters to the `___init___` method.

Someone told me I need to pickle the object before sending it to the cache but all the examples I saw were using .dat files and on appengine you cannot use any file system.

Comment: You *do not* need to pickle an object before storing it in memcache.

Comment: You need to include some sample code that reproduces your problem. We can't tell what you could be doing just from the description you've given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pickle without any filesystem, using pickle.loads / pickle.dumps. For example:

```
import pickle
obj = YourClass(yourparam=...)
data = pickle.dumps(obj)
# and now, store "data" into the cache

# later, get "data" from the cache
obj = pickle.loads(data)

# and tada, obj if the same as before :)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use memcache in appengine. This blog will help you a lot

http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Efficient-model-memcaching